# Waiting for an function to complete before executing the next step - node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am new to node js and currently learning about promises and await/async. I tried the below code but couldn't figure out how to make the code wait till the function hostping is finished. I have also tried promises but couldn't make it wait.

```
var ping = require('ping');
var hoststatus
var hosts = ['google.com'];

async function test()
{
  var connected = await hostping(hosts);
  console.log('connected--------------', connected)
  connected.then(function(hoststatus) {
    console.log('hoststatus--------------', hoststatus)
    if (hoststatus == 1) {
      console.log('faaaaaaaail-------------')
    } else {
      console.log('passssssssssssssssss-----------')
    }
  });
}

async function hostping(hosts) {
  console.log('hosts-----------', hosts)
  await hosts.forEach(async function(host) {
    await ping.sys.probe(host, async function(isAlive) {
      var msg = isAlive ? 'host ' + host + ' is alive' : 'host ' + host + ' is dead';
      console.log(msg);
      if (isAlive == 'false') {
        hoststatus = 1
      }
    });
  });

  return hoststatus;
}

test()
```

Comment: When you use `await` you don't need to use `.then()`.

Comment: take a look at Promise.all

Comment: @Eugen Sunic - thanks for the comment. I tried but still get the same issue. `var ping = require('ping');
var hoststatus 
var hosts = ['google.com'];


const promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  
  hosts.forEach(function(host){
    ping.sys.probe(host, function(isAlive){
        var msg = isAlive ? 'host ' + host + ' is alive' : 'host ' + host + ' is dead';
        console.log(msg);
    });
});
  
  resolve ('host check is completed')
});



Promise.all([promise1]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});`

Comment: since `Array#forEach` returns `undefined` you can't await it - use a vanilla for loop instead - also, I doubt `ping.sys.probe` returns a Promise, since it takes a callback - so you can't wait that either ... and since the callback (`function(isAlive)`) never uses `await`, why make it `async` - seems you've read about async/await and used it everywhere where it's not useful - and one last thing ... why is `hoststatus` global?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want, you should use the promise wrapper of ping and also for..of because forEach doesn't work with async.

- The hostping function has to return a promise that test will wait
  for.
- Use for of inside to loop over the hosts
- use the promise wrapper of ping and wait for probe result
- After all hosts are checked resolve the overall status

Below is modification of your code to get the flow working as you expected:

```
const ping = require('ping');
const hosts = ['google.com', 'yahoo.com'];

async function test()
{
  const status = await hostping(hosts);

    if (status) {
        console.log('All hosts are alive');
    } else {
        console.log('Some/all hosts are dead');
    }

}

function hostping(hosts) {
    let status = true;
    return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
      for (const host of hosts) {
        const res = await ping.promise.probe(host);
        var msg = `host ${host} is ${res.alive ? 'alive' : 'dead'}`;
        console.log(msg);
        if (!res.alive) { status = false; }
      }
        console.log('all host checks are done, resolving status');  
        resolve(status);
    });
}

test()
```

If you're interested in understand more about async, these are good posts to read:
https://www.coreycleary.me/why-does-async-await-in-a-foreach-not-actually-await/

https://itnext.io/javascript-promises-and-async-await-as-fast-as-possible-d7c8c8ff0abc

Comment: hi, thanks for the help. But this always returns the status as false even if all the servers are alive `host google.com is alive
host 192.168.xx.xxx is alive
all host checks are done, resolving status
status----------- false
Some/all hosts are dead`

Comment: changing if(res.alive) to if (!res.alive) { status = false; } works like a charm

Comment: async Promise constructor executor - usually means there's a far better way to write the code

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you wish, we use a for .. of loop to iterate the hosts in order.

The ping library also has a promise wrapper that allows you to skip using callbacks.

You could also use Promise.all to do all the pings and probes at once, but I don't believe this is what you wish to do.

I have included a hostpingVer2 that uses Promise.all if you want to do all pings at once.

```
const ping = require('ping');
const hosts = ['google.com', 'amazon.com', 'itdoesntexist'];

async function test() {
    console.log('hosts: ', hosts)
    const results = await hostping(hosts);
    console.log('ping results: ', results);
}

async function hostping(hosts) {
    const results = [];
    for(let host of hosts) {
        let probeResult = await ping.promise.probe(host);
        results.push( { host, hoststatus: probeResult.alive ? 0: 1, alive: probeResult.alive } );
    }
    return results;
}

async function hostpingVer2(hosts) {
    const probeResults = await Promise.all(hosts.map(host => ping.promise.probe(host)));
    return probeResults.map(probeResult => { 
        return { host: probeResult.host, hoststatus: probeResult.alive ? 0: 1, alive: probeResult.alive } 
    });
}

test();
```

Comment: You are very welcome indeed! Thank you for your question!

Answer (score 0):

You are using await inside `forEach` which is not supposed to work as forEach doens't support promises. Consider changing it to `for..of` or `promise.all`.

Also, your probe function is a callback style which doesn't return promise. You need to wrap it in a promise to await it.

```
function probe(host) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ping.sys.probe(host, function (isAlive) {
      const msg = isAlive ? `host ${host} is alive` : `host ${host} is dead`;
      console.log(msg);
      resolve(isAlive);
    });
  });
}

async function hostping(hosts) {
  console.log("hosts-----------", hosts);
  for(const host of hosts) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-loop-func
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
    const isAlive = await probe(host);
    if (isAlive === "false") {
      hoststatus = 1;
    }
  }
  return hoststatus;
}
```

Comment: you can use await inside a forEach with an `async` callback - it just doesn't work like you think

Comment: can you show me an example or documentation which says async/promises etc works inside forEach?

Comment: define "works" ... of course it "works", it just doesn't "work" as you would expect ... saying `forEach doesn't support promises` is the wrong way of looking at it, since you can quite easily use promises in a forEach loop - of course, most instances of using promises in a forEach loop would work better in a map

Comment: `ping.sys.probe(host, async function (isAlive) {` oh dear ... why is there an async there?

Comment: `var ping = require('ping');
var hoststatus 
var hosts = ['google.com'];

async function test(){
  var connected = await hostping(hosts);
  console.log('connected--------------', connected)
}
async function hostping(hosts) {
  console.log('hosts-----------', hosts)
  
   for (const host of hosts) {
    await ping.sys.probe(host, async function(isAlive) {
      var msg = isAlive ? 'host ' + host + ' is alive' : 'host ' + host + ' is dead';
      console.log(msg);
      if (isAlive == 'false') {
        hoststatus = 1
      }
    });
   }
  return hoststatus;
}
test()`

Comment: If it doesn't work the way you expect it to work. I would say it doesn't work. It's all about terminology. I dont see anything wrong in that.

Comment: but you can use promises in a forEach loop - but you're better off using a map - e.g. document.querySelectorAll  has a forEach method but not a map

Comment: @AshishModi - i tried this but still getting the same error

Comment: @karthik110885 I removed async which was a typo. pls try the updated answer.

Comment: @karthik110885 - use the other answer - it is correct

Comment: @JaromandaX - i am new to node js and still not sure on how to use async properly. Would be really helpful for me if you can point with an example.

Comment: async/await is syntax sugar for promises ... you await something that is/returns a promise - it's all about knowing what a function returns (.forEach returns `undefined` so there's no point awaiting it)

Comment: @JaromandaX - see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

hope it explains.

Comment: @AshishModi - thank you very much for helping with the issue.

Comment: @JaromandaX - i think i understand now. So, i have to understand if a function returns something to use await. thank you very much

Comment: @karthik110885 - a function needs to return not just something ... a Promise ... only a Promise makes sense with await (though you can await a non promise, but that makes no sense)